# Mirror maker 2.0 backup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

In case of an issue where mirror maker 2.0 stops replicating messages from source to destination topic, is there a recommended approach to follow/utility(except for restarting the mirror maker instance) that can be used that will minimize the impact on the destination consumers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the producer to the destination stops, your only option is to restart it.

You need to use external process monitoring / orchestration tools such as `supervisor` or Kubernetes to restart the process/containers that fail.

Comment: Producers are working fine. Issue is with mirror maker not copying the data to destination topic in this scenario.

Comment: MirrorMaker is a consumer **and producer**. Its producer is what "copies"

Comment: I see. Thought you meant a separate external producer client. 
So to conclude restarting the instance is the best option here?

Comment: In my experience, yes.